# Data on radio towers and radio stations in the US

Tags: data-request, historical, technology

Where can I find **historical** data on radio towers and radio stations in the United States? For example, the latitude/longitude, tower height, and transmitting power of every tower that existed in 1930, 1940, etc.?

Alternatively, are there datasets of historical coverage of radio stations? As in, for a certain latitude/longitude, all the radio stations that they (may have) received as of a certain date? The **historical** element is very important here. I'm not looking for recent data or data after 1970.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://www.fcc.gov/licensing-databases/general/search-fcc-databases ? At one point, I mass downloaded some data from them and some of the records mention dates as early as 1904 (there are some 1900 and 1901 dates as well, but these appear to be placeholders). This isn't an answer, because I'm not sure what info they have and if it relates to what you need.

Comment: @BarryCarter I'm familiar with that page, but I'm not trying to *search* for a specific tower or antenna. I'm trying to download information about *all* of them.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to direct you to http://wireless.fcc.gov/uls/data/complete/index.htm

Comment: @BarryCarter Thank you. Is there any documentation on the contents of those files? For example, I downloaded `a_towers.zip`, but it isn't clear from the files inside the archive what they actually are.

Comment: http://wireless.fcc.gov/uls/index.htm?job=transaction&page=daily may or may not be helpful-- actually, I think this is the page I originally downloaded from.

Comment: @BarryCarter It doesn't look like that's what I need. Those data look very recent.

Comment: Are you sure? The archived zip files (not the main ones on the index page) go back for years. Try unzipping them and taking a look.